# new environment with multiple parameters

Tags: environments, parameters

I’m trying to define a new environment which display an image and text below it.

I’ve tried the following code:

```
\newenvironment{essai}[1][]
{   \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{#1}
}
{
}

\begin{essai}{Images/dessin.pdf}
    toto
\end{essai}
```

But, it throws an error that I do not understand:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `' not found.
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be very appreciate

Comment: Remove `[]`: `\newenvironment{essai}[1]{...}{...}`

Comment: @egreg’s comment, *or*:  Perhaps you want `\newenvironment{essay}[2][] {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}} {}`.